# ErrorCode: UnboundLocalError on line 10

Tags: python

Line 10 of the python code below has an UnboundLocalError. Can anyone please teach me how to fix this?

```
def answer(data, n):
    new_data = []
    for each_integer in data:
        new_data = [each_integer for each_integer in data if data.count(each_integer) == n]
    if n > 1:
        new_data = data
    print("\n\nNew Data")
    print(new_data)

supplied_data = [53, 85, 29, 23, 29, 26, 88, 78, 5, 75, 74, 44, 33, 62, 98, 50, 89, 93, 24, 14, 74, 49, 83, 45, 41, 14, 68, 76, 68, 8, 77, 85, 17, 3, 9, 30, 71, 48, 18, 25, 86, 55, 55, 20, 74, 76, 99, 87, 59, 87, 36, 29, 29, 8, 22, 65, 1, 18, 23, 5, 13, 60, 7, 5, 98, 61, 78, 64, 36, 60, 49, 57, 31, 32, 41, 86, 52, 90, 9, 55, 35, 35, 2, 44, 8, 19, 96, 81, 68, 7, 8, 51, 9, 76, 12, 96, 61, 99, 74]    
answer(supplied_data, 0)
answer(supplied_data, 1)
answer(supplied_data, 6)
```

The Traceback

```
    >>> def answer(data, n):
    ...     for each_integer in data:
    ...         new_data = [each_integer for each_integer in data if data.count(each_integer) == n]
    ...     if n > 1:
    ...         new_data = data
    ...     print("\n\nNew Data")
    ...     print(new_data)
    ...
    ... supplied_data = [53, 85, 29, 23, 29, 26, 88, 78, 5, 75, 74, 44, 33, 62, 98, 50, 89, 93, 24, 14, 74, 49, 83, 45, 41, 14, 68, 76, 68, 8, 77, 85, 17, 3, 9, 30, 71, 48, 18, 25, 86, 55, 55, 20,
     74, 76, 99, 87, 59, 87, 36, 29, 29, 8, 22, 65, 1, 18, 23, 5, 13, 60, 7, 5, 98, 61, 78, 64, 36, 60, 49, 57, 31, 32, 41, 86, 52, 90, 9, 55, 35, 35, 2, 44, 8, 19, 96, 81, 68, 7, 8, 51, 9, 76, 12
    , 96, 61, 99, 74]
      File "", line 9
        supplied_data = [53, 85, 29, 23, 29, 26, 88, 78, 5, 75, 74, 44, 33, 62, 98, 50, 89, 93, 24, 14, 74, 49, 83, 45, 41, 14, 68, 76, 68, 8, 77, 85, 17, 3, 9, 30, 71, 48, 18, 25, 86, 55, 55, 20,
     74, 76, 99, 87, 59, 87, 36, 29, 29, 8, 22, 65, 1, 18, 23, 5, 13, 60, 7, 5, 98, 61, 78, 64, 36, 60, 49, 57, 31, 32, 41, 86, 52, 90, 9, 55, 35, 35, 2, 44, 8, 19, 96, 81, 68, 7, 8, 51, 9, 76, 12
    , 96, 61, 99, 74]
                    ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    >>> answer(supplied_data, 0)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    NameError: name 'answer' is not defined
    >>> answer(supplied_data, 1)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    NameError: name 'answer' is not defined
    >>> answer(supplied_data, 6)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    NameError: name 'answer' is not defined
    >>>
```

Comment: This code does not give that error. If you're getting an error, you should post the full traceback. (I originally said it "works fine", but of course it doesn't; both the for loop and the if statement are pointless.)

Comment: Always post **the full traceback**.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it will if `data` is empty and `n <=1`

Comment: But data is not empty, and n is 6.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Would you please take a look at the code again? I kinda changed it but it's still returning the UnboundLocalError. Thanks

Comment: @immanuel None of those throws an `UnboundLocalEror`, so I don't know what you are talking about. I've explained your error. I've even given you working code. This isn't a place where people incrementally help you write code. This isn't a debugging service. If you *do insist* on updating the post with new errors, as always, **post the full traceback** and the input to your function that is giving you the error.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Please take another look at the code. It returns the same error

Comment: You still haven't shown the traceback.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm sorry and thanks for your help so far. Thing is it runs perfectly on my IDLE but I've have to submit it on a terminal and that's where I'm getting the error. Once again, thanks

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I'm sorry and thanks for your help so far. Thing is it runs perfectly on my IDLE but I've have to submit it on a terminal and that's where I'm getting the error. Once again, thanks

Comment: @immanuel How are we suppose to help you if you refuse to give us any information? Likely, you are using the same terminal session and you never actualy reload your script, which you are editing in the text editor

Comment: @DanielRoseman I've updated it with the traceback

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga See the updated question please. I've added the traceback

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have a branch in your logic that uses `new_data` but it is possible that `new_data` is never defined. This will happen when `data` is empty, so you never enter the for-loop body and create `new_data`, and `n <= 1`, i.e. you enter the `else-block`, where you *use* `new_data` without it being defined.

See:

```
>>> answer([],1)


New Data
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 10, in answer
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'new_data' referenced before assignment
```

You could solve this quickly by putting `new_data = data` at the top of your function. Honestly, this approach is really inefficient because it works in quadratic time. `some_list.count` iterates over the entire list each time! So, it is better to make one pass to count element, and then another pass to filter - this will be linear time:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def answer(data, n):
...   counts = Counter(data)
...   return [e for e in data if counts[e] == n]
...
>>> answer(data, 6)
[]
>>> answer(data, 2)
[85, 23, 78, 44, 98, 14, 49, 41, 14, 85, 18, 86, 99, 87, 87, 36, 18, 23, 60, 7, 98, 61, 78, 36, 60, 49, 41, 86, 35, 35, 44, 96, 7, 96, 61, 99]
>>> answer(data, 3)
[5, 68, 76, 68, 9, 55, 55, 76, 5, 5, 9, 55, 68, 9, 76]
>>> answer(data, 4)
[29, 29, 74, 74, 8, 74, 29, 29, 8, 8, 8, 74]
>>> answer(data, 5)
```